# my iPhone (iOS8.4) cannot show the access alert , but in simulator it can show

Tags: ios, iphone, authorization, contacts

I write these code into ‘didFinishLaunchingWithOptions’ function in AppDelegate.m , in simulator it can show access alert like this (not location access but Contact access ): [image]

but in my iPhone(8.4) nothing happened , and the access statue always 'CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined' , then i cannot open ContactViewController .
How can i show the alert in my iPhone?

```
CNContactStore *store = [CNContactStore new];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(granted){
          NSLog(@"allow");
        }else{
          NSLog(@"deny");
        }
}];
```

Comment: It will ask only first time!

Comment: but it never ask in my iPhone,and because of that i cannot open ContactViewController !  @AshishKakkad

Comment: And if you didn't allow first time it will not show also.Delete your app and reinstall.

Comment: I haved tried , delete the app and reinstall , but also show nothing  @Lumialxk

Answer (score 0):

`CNContactStore` is only available in iOS 9.0 and later. Here is screenshot of Documentation:
[image]

Comment: but in this case none of developer will use it , there are many people using iOS8 , we developer have to take care of all client isn't it ?

Comment: @JJ.Yuan Your iPhone is iOS 8.4. This is why you can't get this alert.

Comment: @JJ.Yuan You should use the older contact view controller.

Comment: which one is older contact view controller ? the class name ?

Comment: @JJ.Yuan AddressBook， which deprecated in iOS 9